# How do I use Remotipart with paperclilp to uploaded image and show a thumbnail on the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asyncfileupload

I am using paperclip and Rails 3.2

I have installed the Remotipart gem.

My Model that has an image attachement:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :thumb => "50x50>", :small => "150x150>", :medium => "200x200>" },
                                :storage        => :s3,
                                :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                                :path           => ':attachment/:id/:style.:extension'

      validates_attachment_presence :image
      validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 5.megabytes
      validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
     end
```

Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for @resource, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><%= controller.action_name.capitalize %> Resource</legend>

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :title, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'text_field' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :url, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_field :url, :class => 'text_field' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_field :description, :class => 'text_field' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :author, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_field :author, :class => 'text_field' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :price, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.number_field :price, :class => 'number_field' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :category_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Please select a Category'}) %>
      </div>
    </div>


  <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label 'file types', :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">      
        <% Filetype.all.each do |filetype| %>
        <%=check_box_tag "resource[filetype_ids][]", filetype.id, @resource.filetypes.include?(filetype) %>
        <%=filetype.abbreviation %>
      <% end %>
    </div>  
  </div>

 <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :image, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">   
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
      </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', resources_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
```

I want to be able to upload the file when the file is selected and then show a thumbnail to the user. I understand that Remotipart is supposed to help make this easy but I have not idea how to make it work.

Anyone point me in the right direction?

Update:
I want to be able to upload the file only using ajax so that a thumbnail can be shown of the uploaded image. So the form itself might not be submitted via ajax but the fileupload should.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the documentation for remotipart? It's for remote form uploads via ajax. You don't have a remote form.

See https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart

The good news is that you probably don't need to use remotipart at all!